# Rails 3 some features not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In `rails 4.0` I use to get controller name like this:

```
<% if controller.controller_name == "something"  %>
```

The code is in view and controller function is in actionview helper.

Supposedly it is not working in `rails 3.2`. Is there any other way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "is not working"

Comment: "is not working" means it is not recognizing "controller" function

Comment: Is it `something` or `somethings` ?

Comment: I dunno...didn't even bother to look at it. params[:controller] works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Rails 3.2, for `SomethingsController#show`:

`<%= controller.controller_name %>` returns `somethings`.
`<%= controller.action_name %>` returns `show`

Comment: hmmm...strange it is not working for me seems something is missing well I used params[:controller] works fine : )